# Change iOS status bar font color to white for Ionic 3 app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

[image]

my config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

my app.component

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleLightContent();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. it works for me

```
  statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#1f2933');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to change the status bar background color and the content color in **IOS**.

first I **installed plugin needed.**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar@4 // version 4 since ionic 3
```

then **in app.comopenet.ts**

```
  constructor(statusBar: StatusBar, platform: Platform) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {

          statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
          // overlaysWebView must set to false if you change the background color in iOS with ionic (hence I am using backgroundColorByHexString method )

          statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#c8102e');
          // used above hex color code to set the status bar background color 

          statusBar.styleLightContent();
          // above function  will change the status bar content (icon , text)

          statusBar.show();
          // finally shows the status bar
      });
  }
```

and finally i got what i need

[image: output ios status bar color changed]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the ng-cordova plugin for the status-bar. Then you can do this -

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: This code for ionic 1 and styleDefault() doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this into your  platform.ready().then(() => method

```js
 StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
 StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#00FFFF');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('transparent');
```